# Managing (indexing) large datasets with Meteor and Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How does Meteor handle the process of DB indexing? I've read that there are none at this time but I'm particularly concerned with very large data sets, joined with multiple lookups, etc. and will really impact performance. Are these issues taken care of by Mongo and Meteor?

I am coming from a Rails/PostgreSQL background and am about 2 days into Meteor and Mongo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor does expose a method for creating indexes, which maps to the mongo method [db.collection.ensureIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

You can access it on each `Meteor.Collection` instance, on the server. For Example:

```
if (Meteor.isServer){
  var myCollection = new Meteor.Collection("dummy");
  // create an index on 'dummy', field1 & field2
  myCollection._ensureIndex({field1: 1, field2: 1});
}
```

From a performance POV, create indexes based on what you publish, but avoid over-indexing.

[With oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver), the initial query will only run occasionally- and get changes from the oplog.

Without oplog tailing, meteor will re-run the query every 10s, so better indexes have a large gain.

Comment: Thanks much, Nathan M. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

**Got a response from the Discover Meteor book folks:**

> Sacha Greif Mod − Actually, we are in the process of writing a new
>   sidebar to address migrations. You'll have access to it for free if
>   you're on the Full or Premium packages :)
>
> Regarding indexes, I think we might address that in an upcoming blog
>   post :)

Thanks much for the reply. I'm looking forward to both.